# Android Add two Floating Buttons on one Row

Tags: android

I have the  following view :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/reports"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to place the  two floating action buttons in one row and add again another two more rows of floating action buttons. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

change you xml with below code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/main_view_layout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/reports"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_view_layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/notification2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/reports2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:weightSum ="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/reports"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />


        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/reports"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```